# IBM Watson HyperLink in Chatbot Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-watson

I want to create Hyperlink in IBM watson Chatbot but i am unable to find the solution .Please help me out as i am getting plan text . My code is as below,

```
   let text:String = "<a href=" + "https:IBMWatson.com" + ">" + IBMWATSON + "</a>"
            let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)! // mind "!"
            let attrStr = try? NSAttributedString( // do catch
                data: data,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                documentAttributes: nil)

            let message = JSQMessage(
                senderId: ChatBotUser.Server.rawValue,
                senderDisplayName: ChatBotUser.getName(ChatBotUser.Server),
                date: date,
                text : attrStr.String
            )
            if let message = message {
                self.messages.append(message)
                self.finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
            }
```

Comment: Is your question actually related to Watson?

Comment: Yes !! its related to hyperlink through text in chatbot